# How do you I calculate the difference between two timestamps in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, aggregate-functions, olap-cube

I have a SELECT query to retrieve data I need. One of the needed data is a an "aggregate" function to select two timestamp dates and calculate the difference between them.
Using several resources and websites, they all gave me save answer and it did not work:

```
DECLARE @DATE1 TIMESTAMP = actual_route.end_location_time
DECLARE @DATE2 TIMESTAMP = actual_route.actual_trip_start_time
SELECT 
    CONVERT (TIMESTAMPDIFF, @DATE1, @DATE2) AS time_taken, actual_route.time as date_time
```

I'm getting an error on the "@":  **syntax error at or near "@"**
(This is a portion of the code only but the error is here)

Comment: Just subtract them: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the differenc in Postgres:

```
select (actual_route.end_location_time - actual_route.actual_trip_start_time) as duration
```

I'm not sure why you are using SQL Server syntax for this.  Nor do I know what `timestampdiff` is supposed to be.

Comment: im creating an OLAP Cube where the difference between the two timestamps is a measure to the cube

Comment: the "timestamdiff" function is something i found online

Comment: @JanaNizam . . . Although that is a function in some databases, I have never seen it as an argument to `convert()`.